# RSQLite; is it possible to update a table from a dataframe?

Tags: r, database, sqlite

I am looking at the [documentation of RSQLite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/vignettes/RSQLite.html). I have created a database and pushed some data using

```
mydb <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "myDB")
dbWriteTable(mydb, "mtcars", mtcars)
```

My question is the following: how can I **update** this table, using a data.frame mtcars2, and specifying which primary key to use?

I definitely do not want to loop over all rows of the data.frame...

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using `shQuote()` to concatenate all the values in a list which I then passed to the sqlite `UPDATE` statement:

```
library(RSQLite)

mydb <- dbConnect(SQLite(), "myDB")

dbWriteTable(mydb, "mtcars", mtcars, row.names=T)

mtcars2 <- subset(mtcars, hp >= 150)

dbSendQuery(mydb, paste("UPDATE mtcars SET hp = 'MAX' WHERE row_names IN (", 
                        paste0(shQuote(rownames(mtcars2)), collapse=","), ")" ))

dbDisconnect(mydb)
```